# Queryset does not update on Form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14672407/django-widget-queryset-not-updating) but it does not seem to work for me.
My form updates the choices when I runserver but later when I add a new stop, it does not show up in the list on routes form.

models.py

```
class Route(models.Model):
    DIRECTION_CHOICES = [
        (True, "UP"),
        (False, "Down")
    ]
    STATUS_CHOICES = [
        (True, "Active"),
        (False, "Inactive")
    ]
    TYPE_CHOICES = [
        (True, "AC"),
        (False, "General")
    ]
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Route Name", unique=True, blank=False, null=False, max_length=50)
    direction = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Direction", null=False, blank=False, choices=DIRECTION_CHOICES)
    status = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Status", null=False, blank=False, choices=STATUS_CHOICES)
    list_of_stops = models.TextField(verbose_name="Stops", null=False, blank=False)
    type = models.BooleanField(verbose_name="Type", null=False, blank=False, choices=TYPE_CHOICES)


class Stop(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(verbose_name="Name", unique=True, blank=False, null=False, max_length=50)
    latitudes = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Latitudes", max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
    longitudes = models.DecimalField(verbose_name="Longitudes", max_digits=9, decimal_places=6)
```

I don't think that there is any issue with the view but I can add it if you think there is any

forms.py

```
class RouteForm(forms.ModelForm):
    stops = [(stop.name, stop.name) for stop in Stop.objects.all()]
    list_of_stops = forms.MultipleChoiceField(choices=stops, required=False)

    class Meta:
        model = Route
        fields = ('name', 'direction', 'status', 'type')
```

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Please provide your `view` code too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to use `ModelMultipleChoiceField` instead:

```
list_of_stops = forms.ModelMultipleChoiceField(queryset=Stop.objects.all(), required=False)
```

Code inside form class running only once when django starting, so `stops = [(stop.name, stop.name) for stop in Stop.objects.all()]` list not updating dynamically.